# Loading all data from Rest API call through pagination takes too long and can't do anything until it loads everything

Tags: javascript, html, api, rest, zendesk

I'm having a problem because my app takes quite a while to load because there are thousands of records being retrieved from my API call and I can't do anything while it is loading.

Is it possible that I load these records asynchronously so I can do anything else in my app while it is loading? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Here's my sample code:

```
//this method will retrieve records from api
userPagination(url){

  var requestObj = {
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    contentype: "application/json",        
  }

  ZDClient.request(requestObj).then(function(assigneeUserObject){

    //this will store every user info in assignee_users_fields_all 
    assigneeUserObject.users.forEach(function(assigneeUser){
      this.assignee_users_fields_all.push(assigneeUser);
    }.bind(this))
    
    this.usersNextPage = assigneeUserObject.next_page;

    if(assigneeUserObject.next_page != undefined){
      this.userPagination(this.usersNextPage);      
    }

  }.bind(this), function(err){

  }.bind(this))

},

//This method will call the userPagination() method
getTicketAssigneesUser(){

  this.usersNextPage = "/api/v2/users.json?page=1";
  this.userPagination(this.usersNextPage);
  
}
```

Comment: You mean "asynchronously", right? Because synchronous calls lock the browser while async doesn't. I don't know what "ZDClient" is, the docs refer to ["ZAFClient"](https://developer.zendesk.com/apps/docs/core-api/client_api#client.getpaths). Are you perhaps using an outdated version of the Zendesk Client?

Comment: Hi! Yes, you're right, it should be asynchronously :)

Comment: And what about the "ZDClient"/"ZAFClient"?

Comment: How will I know if the Zendesk Client is outdated? And yes, it is the ZAFClient.

Comment: You might try using async/await, await the Promise and make `userPagination` async.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But still didn't work. My main problem is that my dropdowns having values from API calls are glitching (not sure if that's the correct term) but it goes back up when clicked when the userPagination is still loading.

Comment: I think glitching is a good term for what you are seeing. In your case I would recommend using a "loading" animation that is shown as an overlay above the dropdown which is hidden after all data has been loaded.